# Installing 14.04 from ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso with pxe

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, pxe, debian-installer

We're trying to do an automated network installation using `pxe`.

We installed netboot tools (14.04 LTS) and extracted the`ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso` contents into an http server. We saw that we have to download a missing repository `"main/debian-installer"` (about 50MB) which is necessary for netboot installation, but it is not included within the iso distribution file.

The installation process begins, but failed during "Download installer components" phase saying the installer failed to download a file from the mirror. Is it possible to add the `"main/debian-installer"` repository to the original `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso` contents and if so, how? We want to do automatic installation without Internet access.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.unixmen.com/install-configure-pxe-server-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) what you did?

Comment: No.Because this tutorial is for manual installation.I want to automated the installation.

Comment: You can't automate the installation until you get a working installation.  Complete the tutorial, then find a way to automate it.  If you can successfully complete it, leave everything in place, then script it.